# IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800a0153

Tags: com, com-interop

I'm trying to reference a com component and it is throwing the below error.

Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {xxx} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800a0153.

Specifically the error gets thrown when I try to instantiate an object. I checked that

1. The project being built for x86 processors which it is
2. The com object is registered using regsvr32, and is available in the registry.

I can also see the methods in the object browser, so I know .net is finding it.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: FYI 0x800a0153 = VB_E_TERRREGBADFILE according to err.exe, although I can't find any more information than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error code that's specific to the component.  If you don't have documentation that explains what the code might mean then you'll need support from the vendor.

Comment: Are you sure? The facility code is FACILITY_CONTROL but the error code appears to be in the standard range, not the custom range defined by OLE. Doesn't that point to it being a Microsoft-defined (but sadly undocumented) error?

Comment: @Chris - yeah, I'm sure.  It also covers Automation errors, the SCODE is the app's internal error code.  You can normally get an IErrorInfo to get a description but the OP gets it before he can even get an interface pointer.  GetErrorInfo() might however still work.

Comment: I've contacted the vendor, lets see what happens...will update when I know more.

Comment: The vendor sent me a new set of files that worked, so marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in my comment to Hans' answer, this error code is FACILITY_CONTROL, which is supposed to relate to OLE/ActiveX controls, and has an error code which lies in the standard range (i.e. for Microsoft use) defined in OleCtl.h, but is not documented in the Win32 header files so is probably internal to a Microsoft product such as Visual Basic.

Can you tell us anything else about the COM component you are trying to use?

If the COM component was written using Visual Basic, I think it's probable that what you are seeing is equivalent to the Runtime Error 339 which users of Visual Basic see if they try to reference an OCX control which has some of its dependencies missing. You might look at the dependencies of the COM server's DLL/EXE using `Depends.exe` and see whether you have them all present on your machine.

Comment: I believe it was written in VB6, but haven't been a touch with the vendor yet, to get that and related questions answered. I've used COM explorer to check if any dependencies were missing, and it said there weren't any dependency errors...Will try using depends.exe and get back to you

Comment: I checked using depends.exe and it shows - 2 missing dependencies gpsvc.dll, ieshims.dll - 2 dependencies in red comctl32.dll and ieframe.dll. However, I do see all these on my machine.

Comment: I think you have found your problem. There must be some version inconsistencies which cause the COM server to fail when you try to load it. Welcome back to 1990s DLL hell, "nor are we out of it" [Marlowe 1604]

Answer (score 0):

Back when I had to do a lot of COM work, I used COM Explorer quite a bit from these guys:

http://download.cnet.com/COM-Explorer/3000-2206_4-10022464.html?tag=mncol;lst

I had to install it last year to debug a bizarre COM registration issue with Office plugins.

Also, I have no affiliation with these guys whatsoever (and it looks like the company might be toast anyway).

Comment: What did you look at in the tool? I see the dll registered etc.

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is a menu option for "Find issues" or something like that.  It has been a while since I've used the tool so I'm a little foggy on the details.